# What happens if you move an object without move constructor?

Tags: c++, move, move-constructor

What happens if `std::move()` is called on a user defined object, that defines no move constructor? Is it simply copied?

Comment: You mean with a deleted move constructor? Because if you don't define a move constructor yourself, and all of the objects members have a move constructor, a trivial move constructor is generated.

Comment: Note that `std::move` by itself does nothing to an object. So the answer depends on the context. For example, the moved from object could be used for a move assignment. Or something entirely different. So it is not totally dependent on the type being move constructible

Comment: `std::move` does not move, and `std::forward` does not forward.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, move will fall back to copy. This is how standard containers like std::vector can implement resizing in terms of move, but remain compatible with classes which can only be copied.

However, the class may have an implicitly defined move constructor - see this guidance. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor